# Android: Using TCP to receive stream from Darwin Streaming Server(DSS)

Tags: android, udp, video-streaming, rtp, rtsp

I am working on an Android App to playback rtsp stream from a server which uses DSS.
It works most of the time, but sometimes I can not get it work. I tested with wireshark and saw that the UDP request keeps sending but get no response, and the reason may be that the firewall has blocked UDP packets, I guess. While when I use VLC to open the same RTSP stream, I get RTP response that uses TCP.

For now because I can not change the firewall status, I want to change my app to receive RTSP stream using TCP, which I think using the build-in MediaPlayer/VideoView is not possible. Then how could I do that?

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Bolton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the built-in media player does not support it, then you need to implement your own RTSP client and in the RTSP Setup requests, you need to specify TCP as the transport.

**Standard RTSP setup:**

Track 1:

```
SETUP rtsp://146.64.28.137/TheItCrowd.mm1/track1 RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 3
Transport: RTP/AVP;unicast;client_port=4116-4117
User-Agent: openRtsp (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2010.04.09)
```

Track2:

```
SETUP rtsp://146.64.28.137/TheItCrowd.mm1/track2 RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 4
Transport: RTP/AVP;unicast;client_port=4118-4119
Session: 6B8B4567
User-Agent: openRtsp (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2010.04.09)
```

**RTSP Setup for interleaved over RTSP/TCP:**

Track1:

```
SETUP rtsp://146.64.28.137/TheItCrowd.mm1/track1 RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 3
Transport: RTP/AVP/TCP;unicast;interleaved=0-1
User-Agent: openRtsp (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2010.04.09)
```

Track2:

```
SETUP rtsp://146.64.28.137/TheItCrowd.mm1/track2 RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 4
Transport: RTP/AVP/TCP;unicast;interleaved=2-3
Session: 35B9387A
User-Agent: openRtsp (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2010.04.09)
```

Comment: Thanks you for your help Ralf, but I'm not very familiar with the RTSP issues, could you please give me some more detailed suggestions about it, like tutorials or existing libraries I could learn from:P

Comment: RTSP is a session control protocol (like SIP) and is used to setup the streaming session. It is similar to HTTP in that it is a text-based protocol. The best place to read up on RTSP would be the RFC: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2326. As for existing libraries, there is a great c++ one (http://www.live555.com) but as far as JAVA goes I have no idea. The live555 contains an RTSP client application called openRTSP. You could use this to connect to your DSS server and sniff the RTSP traffic using software such as wireshark. This would help you understand the exchange